# collection of objects returning number

Tags: arrays, object, plsql, sqlplus

I have a house object which has house info in it. I am creating another object - village - which can include 2 - 50 houses in each one. I am struggling on the creation of the village object, more specifically in the loop function - I want village varray include a collection of houses and member function returning the population of a village.

**House object**

```
CREATE or REPLACE type house as object (
  house_no number,
  road_name varchar2(20),
  postcode varchar2(10),
  no_of_residents number,
  member function pass(h house) return number
);
/
```

**Village object**

```
CREATE or REPLACE type village_array is varray(50) of house (
  village_id number,
  village_name varchar2(25),
  population number,
  member function village_population(p v_population) return number  
);
/
```

**village object body**

```
CREATE or REPLACE type body village_array as
 member function village_population(p v_population) return number is

 begin

    /*
    This is where I am clearly struggling to sum all of the house residents
    and returning the population of a village. I have a feeling it is some
    kind of for loop in here somewhere
    */

    then 
        return ;
    else 
        return ;
 end;

end;
/
```

**my village table**

```
CREATE Table Village (
  village_id number,
  village village_array
)
```

Comment: I imagine you need to look up the `village_id` from the object itself and then feed that into a `SELECT` statement that sums over the necessary tables. I've not used stored procedures in Postgres before - can you run `SUM()` over an array of objects?

Comment: I am not sure you'd want to store your population separately in your village - if a house is always only in a single village, then the population of the village is the sum of the number of residents in the houses within that village.

Comment: don't complicate your self with complicate design, it is ok for learning purposes, but if you don't have to deal with this design you have to re-think of more flexible, maintainable db design.